# Does long-term SSRI use cause any permanent changes in personality? Are there any quantitative/qualitative studies looking at this?

Tags: medications, side-effects, cause-and-effect, ssri-selective-serotonin, ebm-evidence-based-med

Curious about counseling patient's on the long-term risk/benefit analysis of SSRI use? Is there any EBM on what personality changes one should expect after X period of SSRI use? Does this change depend on the underlying psychiatric diagnosis?